# How to use a binary search with a two-dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

I'm currently learning binary search. I've been following code example from a book but it doesn't show how to use binary search with two dimensional arrays, only with one dimensional arrays. I wanted to learn both takes to widen my knowledge on this topic.

Here is the code that was written in the book (some of it):

```
package Test;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestMain {
public static void main(String[]args){
    int[]numbers = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int numInput = getNumInput();
    int result = binarySearch(numbers,numInput);
    if(result == -1){
        System.out.print("No Match Found!");
    }else{
        System.out.print("Match Found!");
    }
}

public static int getNumInput(){
    Scanner hold = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num;
    System.out.print("Enter number:");
    num = hold.nextInt();
    return num;
}

public static int binarySearch(int[]numbers,int numInput){
    int first = 0;
    int middle;
    int last = numbers.length - 1;
    int position = -1;
    boolean found = false;
    while(!found && first < numbers.length){
        middle = (first + last) / 2;
        if(numbers[middle]==numInput){
            found = true;
            position = middle;
        }else if(numbers[middle]>numInput){
            last = middle - 1;
        }else{
            first = middle + 1;
        }
    }
    return position;
}
}
```

And here is my code trying to use a two dimensional array:

```
package Practice;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Practice1Main {

public static void main(String[]args){
    int[][]numbers = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
    int numInput = getNumInput(numbers);
    int result = binarySearch(numbers,numInput);
    if(result == -1){
        System.out.print("No Match Found!");
    }else{
        System.out.print("Match Found!");
    }

}

public static int getNumInput(int[][]numbers){
    Scanner hold = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num;
    System.out.print("Enter number:");
    num = hold.nextInt();
    return num;
}

public static int binarySearch(int[][]numbers,int numInput){
    int first = 0;
    int middle;
    int last = 2;
    int position = -1;
    boolean found = false;

    while(!found && first < numbers.length){
        middle = (first + last) / 2;
        if(numbers[middle][first]==numInput){
            found = true;
            position = middle;
        }else if(numbers[middle][first]>numInput){
            last = middle - 1;
        }else{
            first = middle + 1;
        }
    }
    return position;
}
}
```

The output was able to search from 1 to 3. However, when you type in 4 onwards it will give me an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error.

Although I understand pretty much the flow of binary search from the book, I still can't figure out the algorithm using two dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

(Firstly, I think you have picked a rather "uninteresting" problem to solve.)

So how can you generalize from 1-D to 2-D (or n-D)?  Here are a couple of ideas.

1)  Let's assume that we have a 2-D rectangular array of type `int[][]`.  It is a simple matter to (mentally) map this array onto a 1-D coordinate system; e.g.

- [0, 0] -> [0]
- [0, 1] -> [1]
- ...
- [0, N - 1] -> [N - 1]
- [1, 0] -> [N]
- [1, 1] -> [N + 1]
- ...
- [M - 1, N - 1] -> [N x M - 1]

and of course the coordinate mapping goes the other way too.  So ... one approach to a solution to 2-D binary search is to calculate indexes as per a 1-D array and convert to 2-D coordinates to do the array lookups.

2) A 2-D array is actually a 1-D array of 1-D arrays.  So a second approach to a solution is to first perform a 1-D binary search to find the array containing the number you are looking for, then perform a second 1-D search within the array you found.  Note that you can do the initial 1-D search by just looking at the first element of each 1-D subarray.

Answer (score 0):

A big part of any computer science problem is being able to break the overall problem into smaller sections that you know how to solve. For this question, you're asking how to do a binary search on a two-dimensional array, but you only know how to do it on a one-dimensional array. Thus, you should be thinking of this problem in two steps -- find a way to convert a two-dimensional array into a one-dimensional one, and then do a binary search on that converted array.

You mentioned knowing how to do a binary search on a one-dimensional array, so I'll skip that step. Let's look at a conversion method instead:

It looks like you're using Java, and I wouldn't be surprised to see that Java has a built-in function that does it all for you. Let's say that it doesn't, however. We know your numbers[][] array is a 3 X 2 matrix. That means there are 6 elements in the matrix. Our one-dimensional array will therefore have 6 items.

```
int[] new_array = new int[6];
```

We can then do a for-loop through all your initial array's items and fill new_array with them.

```
int counter = 0;
for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
   {
      new_array[counter] = numbers[j][i];
      counter++;
   }
}
```

And now you have a one-dimensional array. Binary search from here to get your final answer.